# Javascript showing alert without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript

when I click submit button it shows the validation right but after that alert message the page is being refreshed and i loos all other datas from the fields :S, how can i make it to still remain the others field filled.

I tried to remove the   window.location.reload() after submit event is called but still not working :S. ANYONE any suggestion?

this is the code:

```
function formValidation() {
  var uid = document.registration.userid;
  var passid = document.registration.passid;
  var uname = document.registration.username;
  var uadd = document.registration.address;
  var ucountry = document.registration.country;
  var uzip = document.registration.zip;
  var uemail = document.registration.email;
  var umsex = document.registration.msex;
  var ufsex = document.registration.fsex;
  if (userid_validation(uid, 5, 12)) {
    if (passid_validation(passid, 7, 12)) {
      if (allLetter(uname)) {
        if (alphanumeric(uadd)) {
          if (countryselect(ucountry)) {
            if (allnumeric(uzip)) {
              if (ValidateEmail(uemail)) {
                if (validsex(umsex, ufsex)) {}
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;

}
function userid_validation(uid, mx, my) {
  var uid_len = uid.value.length;
  if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx) {
    alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
    uid.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function passid_validation(passid, mx, my) {
  var passid_len = passid.value.length;
  if (passid_len == 0 || passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx) {
    alert("Password should not be empty / length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
    passid.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}

function allLetter(uname) {
  var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
  if (uname.value.match(letters)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');
    uname.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function alphanumeric(uadd) {
  var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
  if (uadd.value.match(letters)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('User address must have alphanumeric characters only');
    uadd.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function countryselect(ucountry) {
  if (ucountry.value == "Default") {
    alert('Select your country from the list');
    ucountry.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

function allnumeric(uzip) {
  var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
  if (uzip.value.match(numbers)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert('ZIP code must have numeric characters only');
    uzip.focus();
    return false;
  }
}

function ValidateEmail(uemail) {
  var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
  if (uemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
    uemail.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
function validsex(umsex, ufsex) {
  x = 0;

  if (umsex.checked) {
    x++;
  }
  if (ufsex.checked) {
    x++;
  }
  if (x == 0) {
    alert('Select Male/Female');
    umsex.focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    alert('Form Succesfully Submitted');
    window.location.reload()
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Indentation like that is always a sign of bad code

Comment: @m.edmondson jsbeautifier to the rescue :-)

Comment: @lulzim you should show how that validation function is actually called. And yes, if you don't want the page to reload you should not call `window.location.reload()`.

Comment: @Pointy - I wasn't saying I didn't like your indentation (better than it was before!) it's just there's so many paths through this code...

Comment: @m.edmondson ah yes; I agree; I just did the default indentation so that it'd be at least intelligible.

Comment: this is how i call that function from html file, <form name='registration' onSubmit="formValidation();">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems...

1. Missing return

   onSubmit="return formValidation();"
2. Missing return true;

   if (validsex(umsex, ufsex)) { return true; }